# Java Library to read Microsoft Excel files

Tags: java, excel, comparison

I want to write a program that compares two `Microsoft Excel` sheets using Java.

Is there any existing library (and its documentation) that can help me get started with basic stuffs like reading all the rows and columns of the excel ?

Comment: Just want to add [GemBox.Spreadsheet for Java](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java) into the mix, I find its API to be rather easy and straightforward, for instance see the [reading example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/open-read-excel-file-in-java/401).

Comment: Try Aspose.Cells (https://products.aspose.com/cells/java) component that enables Java Applications to create and manage Excel spreadsheets without requiring Microsoft Excel.  See the simple example in the document (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/java/add-and-retrieve-data/#retrieving-data-from-cells) on retrieving data. 

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), which is a Java API for Microsoft Documents.

And [here is a tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/) on how to setup and get started with Excel files.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Apache POI**

Apache POI, a project run by the Apache Software Foundation, and
previously a sub-project of the Jakarta Project, provides pure Java
libraries for reading and writing files in Microsoft Office formats,
such as Word, PowerPoint and Excel.

http://poi.apache.org/

**2. docx4j**

docx4j is a Java library for creating and manipulating Microsoft Open XML (Word docx, Powerpoint pptx, and Excel xlsx) files.

http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j