# How to process excel with java excluding apache-poi, jexcel and xlsx4j libraries?

Tags: java, excel, file-processing

**What  I already did**

I've already checked [How to read and write excel file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java) and [Java Library to read Microsoft Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351284/java-library-to-read-microsoft-excel-files) but they are all about the above libraries.

I have e java application for processing excel files. I implemented it with apache-poi but I was not able to sign it because xmlbeans.jar contains duplicated entries.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-497

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-499

I saw the workaround in the second issue with patching the xmlbeans.jar but I don't like the idea of workarounds.
I've already re-implemented the code with xlsx4j which can process .xlsx files and jexcel for .xls files.

**Problem**
With two libraries the code is hard to maintain so I'm looking for another way to process .xlsx and .xls

Comment: Asking for libraries, tools.... Is off topic.

Comment: I think it is okay now :)

Comment: You definitely improved your question, and I guess I will upvote just for that. But I am still 80% convinced that the question should be closed ; for being too broad resp. for being unclear. In other words : I am not sure what you are expecting as answer. But maybe you are lucky and you see helpful answers.